# Angular compiles app without any errors, but page is not showing?

Tags: javascript, angular

my Angular app shows me this message:

```
\app\missing\missing-details\missing-details.component.ts|resource�angular-compiler:resource|6|Compilation/assets|chunk105I
```

instead of showing page. Compiler throws no errors.
I'm confused because, I didn't change anything since last working compilation.

Does anyone knows how yo fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to clear your browser's cache?

Comment: I tried and it's still the same.

Comment: maybe some assets that used by your component are missing (images, icons, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Check Browser Console: Open your browser's developer tools (press F12 or right-click and select "Inspect") and check the console for any error messages or warnings. These messages can provide additional clues about the issue.

After running `ng clean`, you can proceed with a fresh build using `ng build`, and this can often help resolve issues related to outdated or conflicting build artifacts.

If the issue persists, try deleting the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling all dependencies using the following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```